# Fortify pointed out an issue: "Portability Flaw: File Separator", but there is no hard-coded separator in the code

Tags: java, fortify

Fortify SCA tool find an issue called Portability Flaw: File Separator, but with the source of those issues, there is none hardcoded file separator such as "/" or "\", only file extensions such as "." exists.

Our customer used Fortify SCA to scan their legacy system source codes. Fortify found Portability Flaw: File Separator issues. It said that the file names which declared in a String array contain hard-coded file separator (this string array is the source of the problem), but I can't see any file separator such as "/" or "\" in those file name strings.

```
    public static final String SYS_SPRAT = File.separator; //this is declared as a class attribute

    String[] fileNames = { //fortify points out here is the source of this issue
            "", 
            "2.5.1aaaaa.pdf", 
            "2.5.2bbbbb.pdf", 
            "2.5.3ccccc.pdf", 
                            .......
            "5.1.4甲甲甲甲甲.pdf", 
    };

    String fileName = null;
    File file = null;

    int iParam = Integer.parseInt(sParam);

    if (iParam >= 1 && iParam <= 26) {
        fileName = fileNames[iParam];
        String filePath = SYS_SPRAT + "home" + SYS_SPRAT + "xxx" + SYS_SPRAT + "ooo" + SYS_SPRAT + "Resource" + SYS_SPRAT + fileName;
        file = new File(filePath);  
    else {
        addFacesMessage("wrong parameter");
        return null;
    }
```

I still can't figure out why there is an issue. Is it a false positive? (but why?)

Comment: It is not only a false positive, it is a non-issue. (1) You are already using `File.separator`, which is already the correct solution. (2) Java deals correctly with both `/` and `\\\` inside filenames on all systems.

Comment: @user207421 The first part is correct , but the second part isn't - Java doesn't deal correctly with backslashes except on Windows. And the Java `java.io.File` API doesn't state anywhere in its public documentation that you can use slashes on all operations systems, so there's no guarantee that it will work on all platforms, now or in the future.

Comment: Does the warning go away if you replace SYS.SPRAT with File.separator on that line?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou hmm....I could give it try. Maybe fortify prefer the separator must only to obtain from the java API and you can't even store it with another variable? But from the report, the source of this issue is the String array which defines the file names. This confuses me so much....

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Turns out it's not working....The fortify insists the problem is still there. All I can do is to explain to our customer and say I can do nothing for this because there is no problem at all....:(

Comment: @TangLiam I encountered this issue recently, and finds out the root cause came from the CJK characters in the filenNames.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Fortify may be overly strict here. Even [their website](https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.dataflow.java.portability_flaw_file_separator) says that using `File.separator` like this should be ok.

I can't see any portability problem using `File.separator`. Even on OpenVMS systems, where file paths are in the format `devicename:[directory.subdirectory]file.ext;version`, the Java runtime internally translates between a `/` separator and the proper VMS format.

First, double-check using a "Find" tool that you don't have any `\` or `/` characters in any of the strings in `filenames[]` (don't just rely on visual inspection). If there is definitely no such character, then proceed with the suggestion below.

Try avoiding `File.separator` altogether. Instead, try using [Paths.get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-):

```
public static final Path RESOURCE_DIR = Paths.get(
        "home", "xxx", "ooo", "Resource");

String[] fileNames = { 
        "", 
        "2.5.1aaaaa.pdf", 
        "2.5.2bbbbb.pdf", 
        "2.5.3ccccc.pdf", 
                        .......
        "5.1.4甲甲甲甲甲.pdf", 
};

String fileName = null;
File file = null;

int iParam = Integer.parseInt(sParam);

if (iParam >= 1 && iParam <= 26) {
    fileName = fileNames[iParam];
    file = RESOURCE_DIR.resolve(filePath).toFile();  
else {
    addFacesMessage("wrong parameter");
    return null;
}
```

Is Fortify ok when you do this?